# Removing extra files generated while creating a dll project in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, pch, dllmain

While creating a dll project in VS17, I see multiple files were created on initialization.

[image]

But whichever  project on C++ I work on, I don't see any such files in their environment. How can I get rid of these files in my environment. Is there any workaround to remove them entirely or reduce these 4 files to one file to reduce mess?

Also before VS17 we used to have `stdafx.h`, it is mandatory to include this header but in few projects I  couldn't find this file, is there any way to remove these initial files entirely?

Comment: `stdafx.h` was default name for optional precompiled header, now by default it is called `pch.h`. Anyway, you can always create an empty project or use your own project templates.

Comment: When creating an empty project, if I build it as dll. Are these files pch, framework contents not required. If yes why and what ll be the difference

Comment: You don't need to keep `stdafx.*/pch.*` but if you don't want it, you have to change the options as well.

Comment: What options? where do i need to configure the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new project in Visual Studio, a precompiled header file named pch.h is added to the project. (In Visual Studio 2017 and earlier, the file was called stdafx.h.)

For more details about pch.h and stdafx.h, I suggest you could refer to the Doc:
[Precompiled Header Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/creating-precompiled-header-files?view=msvc-160)

If you couldn't want to use precompiled header file, I suggest you could choose to not use precompiled headers (Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Precompiled Headers).

When you create a dll project, you also directly choose uncheck Precompiled header or check Empty project.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @puja deo Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

`stdafx.h/cpp` resp. `pch.h/cpp` are the default generated files for supporting precompiled headers. If you don't want them you can delete them. In order to compile you then have to go to your project settings `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ precompiled headers` and change the `Precompiled Header` setting to `Not using Precompiled Headers`.

Before you delete thos files, you should check the `cpp/h` file and put the include files into your files.

Comment: Do you mean the include statements from pch? Do i need to move the include statements into my files?

In that case how do I decide in which header file I need to move them? There are 10header files in my env

Comment: Yes. They might be needed somewhere in your code. I usually do it just by compiling and then fix the errors by adding the appropriate includes. Since I don't know your project, I can hardly tell you where you have to put your includes or what might be missing.